# Angular reactive forms: unable to use ngClass

Tags: css, angular

I have this reactive form input that I want to add a green or red `bottom-border` to depending on its validation. In the below example I only have the validation required and when an input is touched and is invalid I want to add the class `.invalid-input { bottom-border: 3px solid red}`.  I tried the below code, but it isn't working. When I leave the input blank and move away to another input it doesn't show any border. Can someone see why?

```
<input
   id="firstName"
   class="form__input"
   type="text"
   placeholder="First Name"
   (keyup.enter)="getErrors()"
   formControlName="firstName"
   ngClass="{
     'invalid-input': firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)
   }"
>
```

**CSS**

```
.valid-input {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}

.invalid-input {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: try like this [ngClass] ="..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to use ngClass directive angular reactive form add class to any reactive form control so you can easy target the state of the element.

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched , .ng-invalid.ng-dirty{ 
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

> in you question you need to use [ngClass]="..." and use
>   `formGroup.controls.firstName` form control instant

Comment: This is a great answer. I did not know this, very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

it's not good idea to add class directly to input field but:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'invalid-input': formGroup.controls.firstName.invalid && (formGroup.controls.firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)}">
    <label for="firstName">
        First Name
        <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
    </label>
    <input
         id="firstName"
         class="form__input"
         type="text"
         placeholder="First Name"
         (keyup.enter)="getErrors()"
         formControlName="firstName" >
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why it's not a good idea to add a class directly to input?

Comment: @tilly because you can style the text under the error, so instead of using two classes (input + text), you can use only one (container).

Comment: @trichetriche thank you. and no problem if you add your ngclass to input.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason I decided to go this way is that I want to display the error messages on the bottom. IMO it looked better when I just can add a red line on the input element. Tex right below the inpt made the element layout uneven and it seemed too much of a hassle to fix it (limited CSS knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

use the `[class.invalid-input]`

```
[class.invalid-input]="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add more than one class, so I prefered ngClass.

Answer (score 1):

Please try as following:

```
[ngClass]="{'invalid-input': firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched)}"
```

Comment: it might be issue somewhere else

Comment: In the end I got it to work by using this: [ngClass]="{'invalid-input': mySignupForm.get('firstName').invalid && mySignupForm.get('firstName').touched}"

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<div [ngClass]="{'invalid-input': firstName?.invalid && (firstName?.dirty || firstName?.touched)}"> This is test </div>

or 

<div [ngClass]="{'invalid-input': firstName && (firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched))}"> This is test </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue what I've done is two things:
1. Mark the form as submitted using the following:

```
 <form [ngClass]="{submitted:myForm.submitted}">
```

2. Add css for all the invalid input fields within the form:

   form.submitted .ng-invalid
     {
           border:1px solid #f00;
     }

I hope it will help someone who experience similar issue.